# Residential FiOS and port 80

Tags: fios

I'm closing on a house on Monday in a FiOS neighborhood, and I'd like to order service soon.  However, one thing that I need is port 80 and/or 443 open (preferably both).  I won't be doing anything commercial (so I can't justify $100 a month).

Can someone confirm whether or not port 80 is open?  I asked Verizon and they said "yes," but somehow I still don't believe them. (See screenshot below)

[image: chat screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I have residential FIOS.  My inbound port 80 is open.  As to whether your port is also open is hard to say.  Quite a few people in the Verizon FIOS forums on dslreports website reported previously closed inbound was [repored open](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/12566).

> That policy started to change in 2009. Some subscribers reported the port was quietly opened. It appears the change was rolled out as part of network upgrades, so it did not occur all at once.
>
> There has been no official announcement yet from Verizon, so you may or may not have a blocked inbound port 80. At this point, use it if you've got it. If you have to ask for it, Verizon may not give you the answer you're looking for. Yet.

My take on this is your FIOS service is usually directly proportional to the amount of competition in the area.  My FIOS service is very good because I have 3 other cable service providers to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

ISPs **typically** do not block communication on certain ports (although they can), and will allow you to configure that in your router. If anything, most will filter/throttle you depending on packet content using various methods, such as [deep packet inspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection), but that's another question entirely.

ISPs start to get fussy when you're hosting your own high-traffic public web server, or any similar service. You claimed that isn't your intention so you should have no problems.

Comment: "Whether the ports are open on your end is up to you." this is not entirely accurate, ISPs can indeed block certain ports.

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about verizon FiOS. If you actually read on, I stated "ISPs **typically** do not block communication on certain ports." I hope that would be a good indicator for you that they can if needed...?

Comment: I think more home based ISPs block or filter than leave everything open.  I used one in the past that left 80 open, but if you ran a porn site they would shut it down (I wasn't).  The only other thing they didn't allow was IRC.  There is also the possibility of getting a notice about excessive usage.  Another one will not let you send email from SMTP servers other than their own.  Hopefully you will get an answer soon from someone who actually has it.  My sister has it for TV/Internet/Phone, but isn't running any websites.  If I make it there this weekend I can run a test.

Comment: +1 true - but as @Bratch says, I am seeing more and more ISPs in the UK block port 25 and 80 - but unblock them if you request it... simply because 99.9% of users probably don't even know what a port is, let alone need to unblock it!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that consumer oriented high-speed Internet providers generally block 25 and 80 by default, but offer higher priced plans ("business class") where blocking is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Had a static FIOS account for a while.  business so of course those ports were available.  Recently moved and went back to a dynamic residential account.  I host my own homepage and other small personal things...  and sure enough.  My port 80 was open.  No more fussing with odd port assignments for webservices.  And dynDNS works great.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a webserver on port 80, and make sure you open/forward 80 from your router to your server.  Then go to [canyouseeme.org](http://canyouseeme.org/) to test.